# 4 delete vote are required to to delete questions immediately after they are closed?

Tags: bug, specific-question, vote-to-delete

I just saw that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316638/a-project-to-help-greece) was deleted just after 3 minutes of posting:

[image]

Somehow it has 4 delete votes while three should be enough to delete the post.

It gets weirder, see the [revision list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17316638/revisions):

> [image]

Deleted twice, in a difference of one second.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist no it's not.

Comment: Two people voting at the same time?

Comment: It was [deleted twice](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17316638/revisions)!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd How is (was) it not? The question was "Are 4 votes required to delete questions that have just been closed?" and the answer is "No, it only requires three votes unless it's a popular question." - an answer that can be found in the first answer to the question I flagged this as a duplicate of.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes, but in this case four votes were recorded, and it's deleted twice. It's a different issue.

Comment: @Anthony he found a bug, so better revise as a bug then close and forget about it.

Comment: @NullPointer by the way, off topic comment: [your site](http://brightmeup.info/) appears to be dead.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd thankyou .... i am aware about it ... i have changed hosting ... however error is quite dangerous :)

Comment: So maybe consider editing it out of your profiles until fixed? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd good idea ty .... and how possible dup banner works http://i.stack.imgur.com/D07cg.png ?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя excellent question! The user has <3K rep so obviously can't cast close vote; there are no close votes. The only explanation is that when forming this exact type of comment the banner is auto added! Too bad I must go now (lunch time) this would make an excellent bug report.

Answer (score 4):

As ben [commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185976/4-delete-vote-are-required-to-to-delete-questions-immediately-after-they-are-clo#comment570201_185976), probably simultaneous voting:

1. deceze vote to delete.
2. Nanne vote to delete.
3. Mark Baker vote to delete, the internal process responsible for deleting the post is triggered.
4. While that process is still running and before it set the proper internal flag as "deleted" so additional votes are blocked, Quentin cast his own delete vote. Votes count is >=3 so the process for deletion is triggered once again, anew.

The above pretty much explains what happened, waiting for a dev to confirm of course and hopefully fix though it's not a big deal. (post still deleted, no harm done, just weird display)

Comment: Taken the question into account this seems like an Insta-Nuke so I bet many have placed their votes fast so the race-condition might have happened. BTW the messages are not wrong if the events occured this way. The system itself defines what is congruent and what not.

Comment: @hakre not really race condition, the delete process was triggered twice that's clear from the revisions. Question is what caused the double deletion.

Comment: Well, that's not the question. A deletion is caused by votes as you may know.